# Storage management in C

Tags: c, storage

I wrote the program to find out about memory management in C. But I noticed something strange about this program: Why is the variable "a" in memory location 6487580 and not in memory location 6487576.

Because if a pointer is 8 bytes, then it should only reach up to this address. And then the variable "a" would have space there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a=10;
    int *ptr;
    ptr=&a;
    int **ptrptr;
    ptrptr=&ptr;

    printf("adress:\n");
    printf("Adress a: %i\n",&a);
    printf("Sizeof a: %i\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("Adress ptr: %i\n",&ptr);
    printf("Sizeof ptr: %i\n",sizeof(ptr));
    printf("Adress ptrptr: %i\n",&ptrptr);
    printf("Sizeof ptrptr: %i\n",sizeof(ptrptr));

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of the program]

Comment: Pointers are printed with `%p`, not `%i`. `sizeof` values must be printed with `%zu`. The memory layout of variables is completely unspecified and not knowing the details of your compiler, it is impossible to say.

Comment: What @AnttiHaapala said. Also, if you want two objects to sit in adjacent memory blocks, make them adjacent members of a `struct` or array (and even then you might get bitten by alignment requirements). In short: if you care where variables sit, You're Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory alignment. It is likely that the computer you're running on can retrieve data from memory faster or more efficiently if it's stored on a doubleword (8 byte) boundary, or at least the compiler is programmed to make that assumption. If you examine the addresses in binary you'll note they all end in `00`, putting them on a doubleword boundary.

Thus, `ptrptr` is stored on a doubleword boundary at the low-order location and takes 8 bytes. ptr is stored next in memory, and occupies the next 8 bytes. Then 4 bytes are skipped (6487576-6487579) so that `a` will be aligned on a doubleword boundary at 6487580.

Your compiler may have flags which instruct it to align variables on word or doubleword boundaries - or, conversely, to ignore such alignment concerns. Consult your local documentation for such information.